# React Native Android & Genymotion

Tags: android, react-native, genymotion

I'm trying to push the hardware button in Genymotion in order to see the developer activity.

I'm using OSX, the react native tutorial states to hit CMD+M in Genymotion but this doesn't seem to work.

Is there another shortcut? Or a shortcut to simulate shake?
I'm using Genymotion free version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can drag up the bottom menu to expose the hardware `Menu` button.

For anyone that can't get the menu, this is the thing you drag.
[image: drag this]

Comment: Does this work for free version also ? I am not able to expose hardware menu button

Comment: @ChrisMartin: Could you merge your answers to a single one? It makes sense to have all the details in accepted answer

Answer (score 5):

The menu shortcut (Cmd+M on OS X) will only work if the Menu button is visible. So you need to drag the menu as Chris Martin pointed out.